# Best Magento change log & client information tool

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

When working on a Magento project there is obviously a lot going on. New client requests, the release of Magento patches or things you might want to improve on existing projects to keep shops up-to-date, safe or provide better useability.

My question is which project tool is best suitable to keep track of these changes and improvements and is also capable, when needed, to inform the client about the recent changes that have taken place. I'm sensing that clients are getting more informed about the status of their E-Commerce system and the release of new versions or patches of Magento. I've done some research but haven't found a tool that actually fits these needs. I understand there is a not a one-answer-fits-all solution but I'm interested in the tools others might be using and their reasoning behind it.

Comment: Stackexchange encourage more than one answer, so we aren't looking for the one and only. And therefore I think this question IS opinion based, but not primarily. Please keep it open!